# Different hydrostatic pressure on sphere

Tags: pressure, rotational-dynamics, torque, fluid-statics

I want to ask a question that I can't answer it for about 1 year. Does the sphere rotate if we have the sphere or a cylinder that has an point of rotation in the center of the shape holding by a rotatable rod when the liquid no.1 and no.2 is water with different height as shown  in the image?[image] And if it doesn't rotate with similar two liquids, does it rotates with two different liquid types? Does it rotate forever or not?!!

Comment: What do *you* think happens? Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: My theory about that case; it will rotates as the pressure distribution differ from the two sides of the sphere so it will rotates in clockwise direction depending on the different of the force that caused the pressure load and if that happened it would rotates forever as we neglect the friction in the curved shape of the separate plate.

Comment: The sphere will only rotate if there is a *torque* acting on it. Is there a torque here? What direction is the force on the sphere acting at each point?

Comment: I know, If we take the actual force acting on every single point in the surface of the sphere it would all have the direction to the center of the sphere and there is no torque ,But if we take the horizontal components of each force it would make a difference?!!

Comment: What about the vertical components? You cannot take the horizontal but ignore the vertical!

Comment: I know that it couldn't be ,and the vertical component would make a torque in the reverse direction but the two components isn't equal at the same point and on of them increases while the other decreases but is the overall equivalent will make the sphere rotates !!

Comment: But the direction of the *resultant* force at each point is...? The effect of the components, when added, cannot be different from the effect of the resultant.

Comment: I am gonna try to simplify it by using a segmented sphere as with about 8 segments first and try to get some results then step by step increase the segments ..Thank you Sammy :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that it will never rotate whatever you do with the different liquids because the different hydrostatic pressure forces along the circumference of the cylinder are all directed towards the axis so that no torque necessary for rotation can result.

An additional argument against rotation is conservation of energy and also  the impossibility of a perpetuum mobile of the first kind. The liquid levels in the device do not change. Where should the energy for rotation come from?